Are Darboux and Riemann's integral equivalent when using standard partitions?
While studying Analysis, I used many different textbooks: "Understanding Analysis" (Stephen Abbott), "Elements of Real Analysis" (Denlinger), "Calculus" (Michael Spivak).
Initially when dealing with integrals in Calculus, we use the Riemann Integral as a limit of equally spaced partitions (some people may call it standard partitions), here is a picture of a common way of defining it: picture from "Calculus Vol.1" (James Stewart).

For this question, please ignore the fact that in this image the author restricts the integral to the use of the left point for each interval, focusing only on the regular partitions problem.

However, when dealing with a more profound subject like Analysis, I realized that there are many different ways to define the integral, relating to the Riemann Integral there are two main procedures: the Darboux Approach and the Riemann Sum Approach. Both of them are equivalent, that is, a function is Darboux Integrable if and only if it is Riemann Integrable (it is also common to call both of the integrals the Riemann Integral since they are equivalent, as far as I know), as it is proved in many books (see, for example, pg. 215, theorem 8.1.2 of "Understanding Analysis" (Stephen Abbott)).
However, there is one thing I'd like to know: is the equivalence of the Darboux and Riemann Sum approaches preserved when we use definitions such as picture from "Calculus Vol.1" (James Stewart) or picture from "Elements of Real Analysis (Denlinger)"? That is, when integrating with these methods of equally spaced partitions, will it still be equivalent to the Darboux Approach and the non-standard partitions approaches for the Riemann Sum?

No. Dirichlet's dancing function is Riemann integrable if you use equally spaced partitions on $[0,1]$ but it is not Darboux integrable on that region.

How can we be assured that the standard partitions method will produce the correct results for integrable functions? What is the restriction to use them?

@CyclotomicField what is "Dirichlet's dancing function"? If you mean $\chi$ the indicator function of the set $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$, then restricting to equally-spaced partitions will not change the fact that the Riemann sums for such a partition can sum to $0$ or $1$.

@krm2233 equally spaced partitions will always be rational on $[0,1]$. So it will always sum to $0$.

@CyclotomicField I think your terminology must be different to mine. For me, a Riemann sum is given by a choice of partition $\mathcal P =[a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b]$ of the interval $[a,b]$ and a choice of sample-points $c_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ for each $i$, $1\leq i \leq n$. The Riemann sum $\mathcal R(f,\mathcal P,(c_i))$ is the given by $\sum_{i=1}^n f(c_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$. If $[a,b]=[0,1]$, the fact that the partition is regular means that the $x_i$ are all rational, but the $c_i$s can always be chosen to be irrational.

The key theorem here is that a lower/upper Darboux sum over any set of partitions tends to lower/upper Darboux integral when the mesh/norm of partitions tends to zero. This means that defining integral via Darboux sums over standard (or a better word is "uniform") partitions is same as defining it over general partitions.
Another aspect is that if we restrict to standard partitions, but allow arbitrary tags then the integral based on such Riemann sums is same as that over general partitions.
To sum up if we use standard partitions then the Darboux integral is same as Riemann integral with arbitrary tag points and they are same as the more general version of the integral which uses partitions of any kind.
A problem arises when we restrict the partitions in some manner (like using only standard ones) and also restrict tag points (like left/right end points of sub-intervals). In such a case (the typical introduction to Riemann sum in a beginner's calculus text) the resulting integral is just not upto the mark and can't be used as a definition. Such presentation is merely to motivate beginners and should not be taken as a genuine definition of Riemann integral.
